# Python pproxy, make sock5 http request after creating Proxy using SSH

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, proxy, python-asyncio

I am using python-proxy package for converting my ssh connection to a sock5 proxy, facing issues in making sock5 http request after creating server.
Using python package:https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy & reference example:https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy/blob/master/tests/api_server.py

````
import asyncio
import pproxy

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def make_request():
    import requests
    import socks
    import socket
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", 8081)

    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    proxies = {'http': "socks5://127.0.0.1:8081"}
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    }
    url = u'https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/5.152.122.170'
    print(requests.get(url,verify=False,headers=headers).text)
    return "test"

async def ssh_handle():
    print("1")
    server = pproxy.Server('socks5://127.0.0.1:8081')
    remote = pproxy.Connection('ssh://185.110.12.11/#root:test')
    args = dict(rserver=[remote],
                verbose=print)


    await server.start_server(args)
    print("server started now")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await make_request()  #-- after creating server calling function of making http request using proxy
    return "done"

try:

    loop.run_until_complete(ssh_handle())
    loop.run_forever()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)```


  [1]: https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy
  [2]: https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy/blob/master/tests/api_server.py
````

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the issue? It's not clear to me what your exact problem is

Comment: @PirateNinjas want to run two diffrent asyncio loops for diifrent I/O tasks. One loop for creating a sock5 proxy server & one for sending sock request to that server. If i try in a single event loop it blocks the program.